# How to authenticate particular hosts using SpringWebFilterChain

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux

At present I can filter or authenticate incoming requests based of path patterns. But wanted to match it with incoming host.

http://localhost:8080/path

| Scheme | Host | Path |
| --- | --- | --- |
| http:// | localhost:8080/ | demo |

To match path patterns like /get or any we have simple funtion as below

```
.pathMatchers(autPatterns).permitAll()
.pathMatchers(securePatterns).authenticated()
```

But to match header attributes or host there is no straight forward way and need to know how to create a custom matcher.

```
.anyExchange(exch -> matcherForHost).authenticated()
```

```
package org.demo;

import java.security.Key;
import java.util.List;

import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.reactive.EnableWebFluxSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.web.server.SecurityWebFiltersOrder;
import org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.SecurityWebFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.AuthenticationWebFilter;

import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;

import org.springframework.security.web.server.util.matcher.AndServerWebExchangeMatcher;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.util.matcher.MediaTypeServerWebExchangeMatcher;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.util.matcher.ServerWebExchangeMatcher;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.util.matcher.ServerWebExchangeMatchers;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig{

    @Bean
    SecurityWebFilterChain springWebFilterChain(@Autowired ServerHttpSecurity http, @Autowired AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, @Autowired SecurityContextRepository securityContextRepository) {
        String[] autPatterns = new String[]{"/demo/auth/**"};
        String[] securePatterns = new String[]{"/demo/**"};
        List<String> secureHosts = List.of(".*localhost.*", ".*local\\.com.*");


        return http.cors().disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint((s, e) -> Mono.fromRunnable(() ->
                        s.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
                )).accessDeniedHandler((s, e) -> Mono.fromRunnable(() ->
                        s.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)
                )).and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .securityContextRepository(securityContextRepository)
                .authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers(autPatterns).permitAll()
                .pathMatchers(securePatterns).authenticated()
                .anyExchange().permitAll()
//              .anyExchange(exch -> authenticate).authenticated()
                .and()
                .build();
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm try solve same problem, see the code
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/592972/como-planejar-autenticar-multiplas-fontes-de-acesso-spring-api-gateway